# How to auto-load records on page scroll in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, store, extjs4.1, autoscroll

I am working in extjs 4.1. I am eager to know whether there is feature available in extjs to auto load records on page-scroll just like facebook or twitter. How we need to implement it. Do we need to send some extra params on scrolling of page..Can someone please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [infinite-scroll-grid](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/docs/index.html#!/example/grid/infinite-scroll.html). This should solve your problem.

For this you need to implement server side paging and as you will scroll, extjs will automatically send request for newer records.